# Trying to upsample Pandas to have data for every minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database, with a mix of minutely,5minutely, and hourly data points:
My goal is to have 10min data averages, but hwen I plot this out there is missing datapoints and the written CSV file goes from writing every data point to every hour)

The output looks like

```
    2005-03-01 17:00:00,3.25
    2005-03-01 17:10:00,-5.75
    2005-03-01 17:20:00,-6.0
    2005-03-01 17:30:00,
    2005-03-01 17:40:00,
    2005-03-01 17:50:00,
    2005-03-01 18:00:00,2.3
    2005-03-01 18:10:00,
    2005-03-01 18:20:00,
    2005-03-01 18:30:00,
    2005-03-01 18:40:00,
    2005-03-01 18:50:00,
    2005-03-01 19:00:00,2.8
```

The original input, looks like:

```
  01-mar-05 17:10,   1.6,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3536, 0.0214, 1.6726, 1.00,30.567
  01-mar-05 17:15, -13.1,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3540, 0.0214, 1.6729, 1.00,30.550
  01-mar-05 17:20,   3.2,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3542, 0.0214, 1.6731, 1.00,30.554
  01-mar-05 17:25, -15.2,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3544, 0.0214, 1.6731, 1.00,30.534
  01-mar-05 18:00,   2.3,  8.0, 0.0214, 1.8276, 0.0214, 1.6932, 1.00, 0.034
  01-mar-05 19:00,   2.8,  8.0, 0.0214, 1.8312, 0.0214, 1.6973, 1.00, 0.081
  01-mar-05 20:00,   6.8,  8.0, 0.0214, 1.8313, 0.0214, 1.6993, 1.00,  .192
```

The code that I used was:

```
    names= ['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation']
    df = pd.read_csv('Output13.csv', index_col=0, names=names, parse_dates=True)
    df1 = df[['Conc']].resample('10min').mean()
```

And I tried

```
   df=df.resample('1min',fill_method='bfill')
```

thinking that that would fill in all the data points in the original file... but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: could you please define: `it didn't work`?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is a little sparse to get points every 10min when you only get one reading per hour at the end... Since you get missing points, you either have to use the data you have (using `ffill` or `bfill`), or interpolate the missing data.

```
df['Conc'].plot(label='original')
df['Conc'].resample('10T').ffill().plot(label='ffill')
df['Conc'].resample('10T').bfill().plot(label='bfill')
df['Conc'].resample('10T').mean().interpolate(method='linear').plot(label='linear interpolation')
df['Conc'].resample('10T').mean().interpolate(method='cubic').plot(label='cubic interpolation')
plt.legend(loc=4)
```

[image]

Comment: it is only for a few days (over several years) is there hourly the majority it is 1 minute or every 5. 
And I still get :
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Comment: I plottoed it with hourly mean instead, and there is no longer any missing graph poiints i.e

          xexp=df[['Conc']].resample('h').mean()
          xexp['Conc'].plot()
So it probably has something to do with that the CSV file goes to hourly from 5minutely, then trying to take a 10minute average within that

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
In [57]: df.resample('T').ffill()
Out[57]:
                     Conc  Flow      SZ      SB      RZ      RB  Fraction  Attenuation
Date
2005-03-01 17:10:00   1.6   7.9  0.0214  1.3536  0.0214  1.6726       1.0       30.567
2005-03-01 17:11:00   1.6   7.9  0.0214  1.3536  0.0214  1.6726       1.0       30.567
2005-03-01 17:12:00   1.6   7.9  0.0214  1.3536  0.0214  1.6726       1.0       30.567
2005-03-01 17:13:00   1.6   7.9  0.0214  1.3536  0.0214  1.6726       1.0       30.567
2005-03-01 17:14:00   1.6   7.9  0.0214  1.3536  0.0214  1.6726       1.0       30.567
2005-03-01 17:15:00 -13.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3540  0.0214  1.6729       1.0       30.550
2005-03-01 17:16:00 -13.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3540  0.0214  1.6729       1.0       30.550
2005-03-01 17:17:00 -13.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3540  0.0214  1.6729       1.0       30.550
2005-03-01 17:18:00 -13.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3540  0.0214  1.6729       1.0       30.550
2005-03-01 17:19:00 -13.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3540  0.0214  1.6729       1.0       30.550
2005-03-01 17:20:00   3.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3542  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.554
2005-03-01 17:21:00   3.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3542  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.554
2005-03-01 17:22:00   3.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3542  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.554
2005-03-01 17:23:00   3.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3542  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.554
2005-03-01 17:24:00   3.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3542  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.554
2005-03-01 17:25:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:26:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:27:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:28:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:29:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:30:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:31:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:32:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:33:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:34:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:35:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:36:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:37:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:38:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
2005-03-01 17:39:00 -15.2   7.9  0.0214  1.3544  0.0214  1.6731       1.0       30.534
```

Comment: @SLE, if it doesn't help please post a desired output (a sample 5-7 rows) in your question - it will help to understand your goals

Comment: Nope that comes up with the error:
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit